# How do I clear text displayed using Tkinter label().place() function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-label

How do I clear the code of a = Label() ?

## how do I clear the text of this label when using .place() function  a = Label() ?

```
l = IntVar()
t = IntVar()
a = StringVar()

def speed(): 
    global a
    length= l.get()
    time = t.get()
    answer = length/time
    a = Label(frame, text=answer, font="Times 13 bold", bg="Black", fg="WHITE" ).place(x = 100 , y = 160)
    
def clear():
    '''This function is not clearing label of where I am displaying the answer in a = Label '''
    l.set('')
    t.set('')
    #a.set('')<---NOT WORKING
    #a.delete(0,'END')<----NOT WORKING
    #a.destroty()<----NOT WORKING
    #a.configure(text="")<---NOT WORKING
    
ll = Entry(frame, width=30, textvariable=l , border=5).place(x=150 , y=90)
le = Label(frame, text="Enter Length :" , font="Times 16 bold" , bg="WHITE", fg="Black" ).place(x=10 , y = 88 )

tt = Entry(frame, width=30, textvariable=t , border=5).place(x=150 , y=130)
ti = Label(frame, text="Enter Time :" ,font="Times 16 bold" , bg="WHITE", fg="Black" ).place(x=10 , y = 128 )

ans = Label(frame, text="Speed = " , font="Times 16 bold", bg="WHITE", fg="Black" ).place(x = 10 , y = 160)

spd = Button(frame, text="Calculate Speed", width=20, command=speed , bg="Black", fg="WHITE" , border = 4 ).place(x=30 , y = 190 )
cl = Button(frame, text="Clear Text", width=20, command=clear , bg="Black", fg="WHITE" , border = 4 ).place(x=200 , y = 190 )
```

Comment: You can use a `textvariable` for `Label` widget as well.

Comment: After following the answer given below to clear a label, try saying - `le['text'] = ''` or if you want to remove it temporarily, then say `le.place_forget()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that since you have used `.place` with the object definition of the `Label`/`Entry` objects, the return value will be `None`

```
x = Label(<configurable_options>).place(...)  # x is None
```

whereas,

```
x = Label(<configurable_options>)  # defines x as a Label object
x.place(...)  # places x at your desired location
```

This is **True** for all layout managers - `place`, `grid` and `pack`

Moreover, you also need to assign a `textvaribale` to your `Label` to be able to clear them (thanks @CoolCloud)

```
l = StringVar()
l1 = Label(..., textvariable=l)
```

If you do not wish to add a textvariable, then simply use `.config` method of `Label`.

```
l1.config(text='')
```

Comment: Will this clear the label?

Comment: yes. This clears the label. Moreover, this answer was more of a guideline as to how you should be writing tkinter elements

Comment: Hmmm, i dont see how his code will work, because he hasnt assigned a `textvariable` to the labels anyway, or am i wrong

Comment: @CoolCloud yep, you are right. he needs to define `l` as the textvariable for Label `l1`. Thanks. I'll update the answer

Comment: @CoolCloud I have assigned the text variables the only problem was that it was not clearing the text of the label where I was  displaying the answer. with the guidelines of **FrainBr33z3** its clearing the text of 'a = Label( text= answer) '